# Cant send the data from my "sender.java" to my "receiver.java". (Java Socket Programming)

Tags: java, unix, serversocket

I am having issues with my two java programs communicating with each other. The problem is that the "receiver.java" program that acts as the server cannot run / start or receive data from the "sender.java" program. The sender program works and runs fine though on port :4444. I am getting Java socket connection error so it has something to do with connection.

FINAL UPDATE EDIT*****: It works fine now, I fixed the first problem by changing the ports to match. (4444). And I passed the receiver to connect through (IP,4444) NOT (localhost,4444) so I ran "sender.java" on my local IP address which is 127.*.*.*:4444 and "receiver.java" on (localhost:4444) and they connected and the receiver received the checksum data I inputed. Thanks all!

1. Check_Sum_Sender.java

```
// Java code for Checksum_Sender 
package checksum_sender; 

import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 
import java.util.*; 

public class Checksum_Sender  

{ 
    // Setting maximum data length 
    private int MAX = 100; 

    // initialize socket and I/O streams 
    private Socket socket = null; 
    private ServerSocket servsock = null; 
    private DataInputStream dis = null; 
    private DataOutputStream dos = null; 

    public Checksum_Sender(int port) throws IOException 
    { 
        servsock = new ServerSocket(port); 

        // Used to block until a client connects to the server 
        socket = servsock.accept(); 

        dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); 
        dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 

        while (true)  
        { 
            int i, l, sum = 0, nob; 
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
            System.out.println("Enter data length"); 
            l = sc.nextInt(); 

            // Array to hold the data being entered 
            int data[] = new int[MAX]; 

            // Array to hold the complement of each data 
            int c_data[] = new int[MAX]; 

            System.out.println("Enter data to send"); 

            for (i = 0; i < l; i++)  
            { 
                data[i] = sc.nextInt(); 

                // Complementing the entered data 
                // Here we find the number of bits required to represent 
                // the data, like say 8 requires 1000, i.e 4 bits 
                nob = (int)(Math.floor(Math.log(data[i]) / Math.log(2))) + 1; 

                // Here we do a XOR of the data with the number 2^n -1, 
                // where n is the nob calculated in previous step 
                c_data[i] = ((1 << nob) - 1) ^ data[i]; 

                // Adding the complemented data and storing in sum 
                sum += c_data[i]; 
            } 

            // The sum(i.e checksum) is also sent along with the data 
            data[i] = sum; 
            l += 1; 

            System.out.println("Checksum Calculated is : " + sum); 
            System.out.println("Data being sent along with Checkum....."); 

            // Sends the data length to receiver 
            dos.writeInt(l); 

            // Sends the data one by one to receiver 
            for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) 
                dos.writeInt(data[j]); 

            // Displaying appropriate message depending on feedback received 
            if (dis.readUTF().equals("success"))  
            {    
                System.out.println("Thanks for the feedback!! Message received Successfully!"); 
                break; 
            } 

            else if (dis.readUTF().equals("failure"))  
            { 
                System.out.println("Message was not received successfully!"); 
                break; 
            } 
        } 

        // Closing all connections 
        dis.close(); 
        dos.close(); 
        socket.close(); 
    } 

    // Driver Method 
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
    { 
        Checksum_Sender cs = new Checksum_Sender(4444); 
    } 
}
```

2. Check_Sum_Receiver.java

```
// Java code for Checksum_Receiver 
package checksum_sender; 

import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 

public class Checksum_Receiver { 

    // Initialize socket and I/O streams 
    private Socket s = null; 
    private DataInputStream dis = null; 
    private DataOutputStream dos = null; 

    // Constructor to put ip address and port 
    public Checksum_Receiver(InetAddress ip,int port)throws IOException 
    { 

        // Opens a socket for connection 
        s = new Socket(ip,port); 

        dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream()); 
        dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()); 

        while (true) 
        {   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
            int i, l, nob, sum = 0, chk_sum; 

            // Reads the data length sent by sender 
            l = dis.readInt(); 

            // Initializes the arrays based on data length received 
            int c_data[] = new int[l]; 
            int data[] = new int[l]; 

            System.out.println("Data received (alond with checksum) is"); 

            for(i = 0; i< data.length; i++) 
            {    
                // Reading the data being sent one by one 
                data[i] = dis.readInt(); 
                System.out.println(data[i]); 

                // Complementing the data being received 
                nob = (int)(Math.floor(Math.log(data[i]) / Math.log(2))) + 1;  
                c_data[i] = ((1 << nob) - 1) ^ data[i]; 

                // Adding the complemented data 
                sum += c_data[i]; 
            } 
            System.out.println("Sum(in ones complement) is : "+sum); 

            // Complementing the sum 
            nob = (int)(Math.floor(Math.log(sum) / Math.log(2))) + 1;  
            sum = ((1 << nob) - 1) ^ sum; 
            System.out.println("Calculated Checksum is : "+sum); 

            // Checking whether final result is 0 or something else 
            // and sending feedback accordingly  
            if(sum == 0) 
            {    
                dos.writeUTF("success"); 
                break; 
            }      
            else
            {    
                dos.writeUTF("failure"); 
                break; 
            } 
        } 

        // Closing all connections 
        dis.close(); 
        dos.close(); 
        s.close(); 
    } 

    // Driver Method 
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException 
    {    
        // Getting ip address on which the receiver is running 
        // Here, it is "localhost" 
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); 
        Checksum_Receiver cr = new Checksum_Receiver(ip,4444); 
    }     
}
```

Comment: If you're starting your `ChecksumSender` (also look at names) on port `47096` why are you attempting to connect to port `5000` in the receiver?  Look at this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html, the server starts on 4444 and the client connects to 4444.  This should be the same regardless of language.

Comment: lol wow I changed them both to port 4444 and repacked and the receiver is now actually running!!! I did this before but I wasn't repackaging them right so that was the issue. However, I am getting a new error now:    "Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" ..... BUT thank you so much as i made great progress, I can probably maybe fix this issue after i investigate it more. Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE!!!!: I fixed it guys.....Im an idiot....I passed the receiver to the localhost " IP " and NOT localhost....so I ran them both on this address: "127.0.0.1:4444" and it worked!!!!

Comment: So why did you describe a connection refusal as "csn't send data"?

Comment: And what does [tag:checksum] have to do with the problem you encountered?

Comment: @user207421 Sorry for rambling about the checksum in this problem. This was my first post ever on this forum. Anyway, I got rid of talking about the checksum because that was never the problem to begin with. I stated that in the first sentence before and at the end of the sentence I explained the problem was the receiver program not running / starting, and when i figured out how to run it, it wasn't receiving the data from the sender program i inputed. Its all fixed now and I edited the question. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who reads this and finds this answer helpful to them. These were the fixes for my problems:

**1:** Make sure the port numbers match on both sender and receiver program. *(sender:port=receiver:port)*

**2:** Use your local IP address for the sender *(127.0.0.1:port)* and use *(localhost:port)* for the receiver! OR vice versa.

**3:** Then for data input start the sender program first but don't input anything yet, then start the receiver so the data-stream can be connected. Then input data as you like!

Comment: (2) accomplishes nothing. 127.0.0.1 and `"localhost"` are entirely equivalent.